# how to print text on heroku logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

As far as I know, the best way to debugg in production with heroku is verifying it's logs. I want to display a variable as a string to this terminal but I couldn't yet with the configuration below.

from the command:

```
heroku logs
```

I want to display from a given page's controller something like:

```
puts "****test****"
```

this [heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log) is saying that it needs to config with:

**config.ru**

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

and I write between these two lines:

```
require_relative 'config/environment'

$stdout.sync = true   # <----

run Rails.application
```

In the same article, is saying that we need to add `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` into "into your app’s configuration to get stdout logging".

So, added inside **production.rb** between these lines:

```
  # (...)

  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) # <---

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # (...)
```

That doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `production.rb` file you should have this configuration (it should already be there, but doesn't hurt to make sure)

```
if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
  logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
  config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
end
```

This tells you that you need to make sure that the `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT` environment variable has a value in production.

```
$ heroku config:set RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=enabled
```

Then, in your controller, you can call something like

```
logger.debug "****test****"
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why but it doesn't work in production to me. And 'logger.debugg' results an error. Only with 'logger.info' it pass through (in development of course).

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? And what error are you getting with `logger.debug`

Comment: Rails 5.0.1, Ruby 2.5.1

Comment: Thank you, it's working, sorry for answer late because I wrote wrong the 'logger.debug'